# How can I delay splash screen hide on using PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, ios8, splash-screen

I have a phonegap app that I am targeting for iPad. It works well on iOS 7. We now updated an iPad mini to iOS 8 and the splash screen hides you then get 1-2 seconds of white screen before the page loads. I'm guessing there are too many resources getting loaded before the screen will render. Is there a way to make the splash screen visible longer? It looked like this was possible in older versions of PhoneGap but I'm not finding anything for recent versions

Tried this in my index.html but it did not create any visible difference

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use device APIs
        setTimeout(function() {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }, 2000);
    }

    </script>
```

So I then opened up the safari web inspector, and then looked at the javascript console. I then checked to see if I could access splash from the navigator object and it does not seem to be available.

[image]

Comment: What version of Phonegap and version of the plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Put this after deviceready, it seems that duration has been deprecated from 3.1 version:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: So do I need to set <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" /> ?

Comment: I'n not sure it is needed. It seems that default value for SplashScreenDelay is 3000 ms https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens

Comment: The default delay you reference is under the Android section. There seems minimal info on ios just where to put the images. Also above, I included an update where I tried accessing the navigator.splashscreen but that property does not exist.